# Can't Parse webhook of razropay

Tags: php, json, webhooks, razorpay

The webhook pings successfully, but I'm unable to parse it, I spent 4 hours still no luck, I tried all methods but still failed,I just don't know why is this happening , i have used it same for stripe webhook, it works but this is working for razor pay

Below is the header and response I receive on my webhook:
Source: https://webhook.site/

**Headers**

```
connection  close
accept-encoding gzip
x-razorpay-signature    f0087994b59ee5ec1b1828a87f794c89bb398033a428bb79971875e5f295322e
x-razorpay-event-id Gb5kMCdcAZ8jJ8
request-id  Gb5kMCdcAZ8jJ8
content-type    application/json
content-length  1053
user-agent  Razorpay-Webhook/v1
host    webhook.site
```

Raw content

```
    {
  "entity": "event",
  "account_id": "acc_DOXUp08NQX6Sr9",
  "event": "payment.captured",
  "contains": [
    "payment"
  ],
  "payload": {
    "payment": {
      "entity": {
        "id": "pay_Gb5kLMBMjON6So",
        "entity": "payment",
        "amount": 1132,
        "currency": "USD",
        "base_amount": 82174,
        "base_currency": "INR",
        "status": "captured",
        "order_id": "order_Gb5kEv5w8pveU5",
        "invoice_id": null,
        "international": false,
        "method": "card",
        "amount_refunded": 0,
        "refund_status": null,
        "captured": true,
        "description": null,
        "card_id": "card_Gb5kLUZEfKlXF4",
        "card": {
          "id": "card_Gb5kLUZEfKlXF4",
          "entity": "card",
          "name": "231231231231231231",
          "last4": "8826",
          "network": "Visa",
          "type": "prepaid",
          "issuer": "SBIN",
          "international": false,
          "emi": false,
          "sub_type": "business"
        },
        "bank": null,
        "wallet": null,
        "vpa": null,
        "email": "niteshkmr366@gmail.com",
        "contact": "+918169179450",
        "notes": {
          "ytsubme_account_email": "niteshkmr366@gmail.com",
          "phone": "8169179450"
        },
        "fee": 1644,
        "tax": 0,
        "error_code": null,
        "error_description": null,
        "error_source": null,
        "error_step": null,
        "error_reason": null,
        "acquirer_data": {
          "auth_code": null
        },
        "created_at": 1613226609
      }
    }
  },
  "created_at": 1613226609
}
```

**My PHP Code:**

```
<?
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');           
$obj = json_decode($data);
file_put_contents('data.txt',$data);
//data.txt file is still empty
?>
```

Comment: I'm confused: where are you seeing the raw content if your attempt to save it to a file is failing? And why would populating `$obj` make a difference to what's in `$data`?

Comment: @IMSoP I have added two webhook on to my site, another web hook to  debugging site (webhoook.site) where I see the live raw content and header ,the sender  is sending - i have pasted that. but on my site , i dont get any response.

Comment: Well, parsing an empty string as JSON isn't going to make it not empty, so you need to sort out why it's empty before you worry about parsing it.

Comment: @IMSoP here is the testing url : https://webhook.site/#!/31374d1c-2dce-443e-bc63-6c7b899d6a94/b5b23bf5-0e7a-4a88-b221-1eeffe618d86/1

Comment: @IMSoP i have checked it there is only this 3 line of codes, i think i need to add a header to my php file ?

Comment: Just a possibility: I notice your code uses the short `<?` opening tag rather than `<?php` That can be disabled in the PHP configuration, so it's possible your code isn't running at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @[IMSoP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157957/imsop),
For reminding me to sort out why it's empty before you worry about parsing it.

My webhook was pinging to the URL where login was necessity,
)more info : SESSIONS : i.e. if session wasn't set it was redirecting them to / page.)

Due to which I was getting empty data ,feeling so dumb about this.